# Runtime of following algorithm (example from cracking the coding interview)

Tags: algorithm

One of problem in cracking the coding interview book asks the run-time for following algorithm, which prints the powers of 2 from 1 through n inclusive:

```
int powersOf2(int n) {
    if (n < 1) return 0;
    else if (n == 1) print(1); return 1;
    else
    {
        int prev = powersOf2(n/2);
        int curr = prev * 2;
        print(curr); 
        return curr;
    }
}
```

The author answers that it runs in O(log n).

It makes perfect sense, but... n is the VALUE of the input! (**pseudo-sublinear** run-time).

Isn't it more correct to say that the run-time is O(m) where m is the length of input to the algorithm? (O(log(2^m)) = O(m)).

Or is it perfectly fine to simply say it runs in O(log n) without mentioning anything about pseudo- runtimes...

I am preparing for an interview, and wondering whether I need to mention that the run-time is **pseudo-sublinear** for questions like this that depend on value of an input.

Comment: Need? I'd say no.  Should? Of course, an interview gives you a chance to show off your knowledge.

Comment: How do you justify that this time complexity of this algorithm is O(n)? I don't get it at all. BTW, is O(log n) polynomial?!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say O(log n). The total number of powersOf2 calls are log(n) because it is called every time n is halved until 1 or 0.

Comment: At the interview just say its time complexity is O(log n) which is logarithmic. IN THIS CASE, the pseudo-polynomial is not even applicable.

Comment: @mok Why is it not applicable? The run-time depends on the numeric value of the input. If N = 16, then input length will be 4 bits. The above algorithm runs in O(lg16) = O(4) which is logarithmic to the value, but linear to the input length.

Comment: Is it polynomial? Is your algorithm running in exponential time regarding the length of the input?

Comment: Oh, man, I picked out a terrible example. Pseudo-sublinear time would be correct in above example... but you get the point that I am trying to ask...

Answer (score 2):

I think the term that you're looking for here is "[weakly polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time)," meaning "polynomial in the number of bits in the input, but still dependent on the numeric value of the input."

Is this something you *need* to mention in an interview? Probably not. Analyzing the algorithm and saying that the runtime is O(log n) describes the runtime perfectly as a function of the input parameter n. Taking things a step further and then looking at how many bits are required to write out the number n, then mentioning that the runtime is linear in the size of the input, is a nice flourish and might make an interviewer happy.

I'd actually be upset if an interviewer held it against you if you didn't mention this - this is the sort of thing you'd only know if you had a good university education or did a lot of self-studying.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that an algorithm takes O(N) time, and it's not specified what N is, then it's taken to be the size of the input.

In this case, however, the algorithm is said to to take O(n) time, where `n` identifies a specific input parameter.  That is also perfectly OK, and is common when the size of the input isn't what you would practically want to measure against.  You will also see complexity given in terms of multiple parameters, like O(|V|+|E]) for graph algorithms, etc.

To make things a bit more confusing, the input value `n` is a single machine word, and numbers that fit into 1 or 2 machine words are usually considered to be constant size, because in practice they are.

Since giving a complexity in terms of the size of `n` is therefore not useful in any way, if you were asked to give a complexity without any specific instructions of how to measure the input size, you would measure it in terms of the *value* of `n`, because that is the useful way to do it.